# Printing information from database to console program

Tags: java, mysql, resultset

I have a quick question. I'm a beginner programmer and for school we need to make a little console code which prints the result of a query in the console. How ever much I tried it didnt work me, all I get is some strange text instead of the query result.

Here's my main class, I also have a second class which is called `SimpleDataSourceV2` (this class holds the code for making connection to the mySQL database.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
    Connection conn = SimpleDataSourceV2.getConnection();

      doQuery(conn);

      conn.close();

    }
    catch ( Exception e){
        System.out.print(e);
    }
}

public static void doQuery(Connection conn) {
    try {

        Statement stat = conn.createStatement();

        ResultSet result = stat.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM employee");

        while (result.next()) {
            System.out.println(result);
        }

        result.close();

        stat.close();

    }
    catch ( SQLException e){
        System.out.print(e);
    }
}
```

This are the two methods which I use. The employee table holds different information such as name, adress, city, etc.

Here is what my output is:

```
run:

com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet@2bd1c812
com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet@2bd1c812
com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet@2bd1c812
com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet@2bd1c812
com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet@2bd1c812
com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet@2bd1c812
com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet@2bd1c812
com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet@2bd1c812
com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet@2bd1c812
com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet@2bd1c812

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

Can anyone please tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you directly try to print `ResultSet`, you will get the output like that only. If you know number of columns, then write a loop and print column values

```
while (result.next()) {
    for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= numberOfColumns; columnIndex ++){
        System.out.println(columnIndex + "<====>" + result.getString(columnIndex));
    }
}
```

If you don't know the column count, you can get it using [ResultSetMetaData](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html) like this

```
 java.sql.ResultSetMetaData rsmd = result.getMetaData();
 int numberOfColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();
```